# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Brower no support (Facebook)

Tags: php, html, facebook, simple-html-dom

I'm using the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to get the contents of a facebook album just that the problem is returning and that I need to update my browser

My code

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html("https://www.facebook.com/pg/natgeo/photos/?tab=album&album_id=431705768950");
echo $html;
```

Return this

[image]

Comment: Facebook detects your browser capabilities. Start by faking your user agent and see what happens.

Comment: Scraping Facebook pages is against their ToS. If you want to get access to this kind of data, do it in the way you’re supposed to - by using their API.

Comment: They know how and that https://embedsocial.com/ can get the photos without any kind of token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this way !!

```
$url = "https://www.facebook.com/pg/natgeo/photos/?tab=album&album_id=431705768950";

$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'header'=>"User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$html = file_get_html($url , false, $context);
```